# Installing features using DirectorApplication

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

I need to install features from update site when my product is launched and certain criteria is met. I read up on provisioning p2 repository and using API to install IU from there. I also found DirectorApplication for director and got pretty far with it, basically:

```
DirectorApplication app = new DirectorApplication();
String[] args = new String[]{"-repository", "http://myRepo","-installIU", "myFeature.feature.feature.group", "-destination", "myDestination"};
app.run(args);
```

myFeature is being installed but is running into some issues with missing dependency plugins. I am running this code from source and installing into finished product, so perhaps something is wrong there.

My main question so far is am I on the right track? Should I be using DirectorApplicaton directly (I know about implications of using internal packages) or provisioning my update site into p2 repository and follow [this documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_api_overview.htm)? If it's the latter, is there more involved documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the DirectorApplication to install into the running Eclipse - AFAIK it is not meant for this. Instead, you should rather use the p2 API to manipulate the currently running installation.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Using p2 API definitely gives me more control of what is going on. Thanks.